# Nested if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a function to return '0' or '1' depending on the result of nested if else statements. Using MSSQL.

```
ALTER FUNCTION udf_check_names_starting_with_quotationmark
(@string NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @condition INT
  SET @string = LTRIM(@string)
  SET @string = RTRIM(@string)

  IF (PATINDEX('"%', @string) !=0)
    BEGIN
      SET @condition = 1
    END
  ELSE IF (PATINDEX('%"%', @string) !=0) 
    BEGIN
      SET @condition=1
    END
  ELSE IF (PATINDEX('%"', @string) !=0)
    BEGIN
      SET @condition = 1
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @condition=0
    END
  RETURN @condition
END
```

Everything is working fine with this. Is there a better way to achieve this (I have tried using OR but SQL editor showing an error, not recognizing the OR).

Answer (score 6):

```
SET @condition = (case when PATINDEX('"%', @string) !=0 or 
                            PATINDEX('%"%', @string) !=0 or 
                            PATINDEX('%"', @string) !=0 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help.. I was playing around with Case but could not get it to work, my bad.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Surely this can be simplified to:

```
  IF (PATINDEX('%"%', @string) !=0) 
    BEGIN
      SET @condition=1
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @condition=0
    END
```

- since `PATINDEX('%"%', @string)` will be > 0 where either `PATINDEX('"%', @string)` or PATINDEX('%"', @string) are > 0?